# ADF-Oracle set number in id and can't be found in javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-adf

in ADF I want to find an input text in java script. I test some codes like:

```
AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('root:it1::content');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('it1').value;
```

but I couldn't find the input text.
I saw the HTML source and I found that the id is something like that:

```
id="r1:2:it1::content"
```

so my problem is "2" that is between r1 and it1. sometimes this number gets 0 in this page so i can't find the id again. can you help me?

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-execute-client-javascript-in-an-adf-java-bean-action/

Answer (score 0):

ADF uses variable numbers in ids based on how it builds the page.

If you must, you can instead get the parent component and iterate through the children until you find it1.

That is not ideal however and it is rare that you need truly JS in ADF development.  If you provide what you want to accomplish and a sample from your jsf/jsp, someone may be able to provide a more helpful solution.